# Using VS Code with native Windows OpenSSH client

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, openssh, ssh-agent

I'm trying to pass from Putty/Pagent/plink to Windows OpenSSH native client.

I already managed to do this in `TortoiseGit`, but with the main problem with `VSCode` seem to be I can't set which ssh agent to use.

I enabled the `OpenSSH` agent service on Windows to start automatically and added my open ssh key with `ssh-add`.

Every time i try to push from `VSCode` all i got is an error message with

> Git: FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: public key)

When trying to push from terminal I got also

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

As already said, with `TortoiseGit` I have no problem at all, and the only differences are that in TortoiseGit I set the `ssh-agent`.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to confirm your System environment variable `GIT_SSH` points to the `ssh` within Git: `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your Windows OpenSSH.  If you run `ssh -V` from a PowerShell window and see `OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1`, this is probably the case.  The instructions for upgrading are available in the [Install Win32 OpenSSH Wiki](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH).

### General

VS Code uses the Windows version of OpenSSH.

- The config file that you change in VS Code is located in `/Users/<username>/.ssh/config`
- The default location/name of a key is at `/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa`.

### Example

- Local: Windows 10 machine with VS Code and the very awesome Remote - SSH extension installed
- Remote: Ubuntu, where I use git for development and need my private key available
- Since the remote is shared, I want to use SSH agent forwarding and keep my private key(s) on my local machine

###### Config file:

```
Host mybox
  HostName actual.ip.or.name.of.mybox.com
  User myusername
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ForwardAgent yes
```

###### PowerShell Commands (Run as Administrator)

```
Start-Service ssh-agent
ssh-add C:\Users\<username>\.ssh\id_rsa       # private key to add
ssh-add -L                                    # list keys added
Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic  # optional
```